# PHP rtrim() Function Weird Behavior

Tags: php, character-trimming

Please let me know if you see something wrong here.  I believe there is some kind of issue with the rtrim function.  I have spent far too much time looking into this.  Haha *cries a little*

```
<?php
$items = array('HTML1.html','PHP1.html','Javascript.html');

foreach ($items as $item) {
echo '<br>Trimmed: ' . rtrim($item,'.html') . '<br>Untrimmed: ' . $item . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Expected output should be "Javascript" but I am getting "Javascrip" for the third item in the array.

Comment: The trim functions removes characters, not phrases, so it will trim `.`, `h`, `t`, `m`, and `l` where it sees it at the end of the string.

Comment: `rtrim()` strips _individual characters_, not substrings. If you're just trying to cut the extension off, you might use `basename($item, '.html')`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I ended up writing my own function to remove the filename extensions.

    function remove_extension ($file) {
     foreach (str_split($file) as $char) {
      if ($char != '.') {
       $temp .= $char;
       } 
      else {
       return $temp;
      }
     }
    }

basename would work too!  I am unsure why I was unable to locate that function.  I appreciate your help!